# How to remove a section of a string using escape character

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, escaping

I have a set of NSString representing the names of the files in a directory. These names are structured this way:

XXXXXXXXX_YYYY_AAAA.ext

All the sections separated by "_" are of variable length and I would only have the first.
How can I separate the first part from the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the NSString method `componentsSeparatedByString:`. That will tokenize a string and return you an array. Something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [@"XXXXXXXXX_YYYY_AAAA.ext" componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
NSString *firstToken = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the position of the `'_'` character, then get a substring 0 through that position. Note that `substringToIndex:` does not include the character at the index position.

```
NSRange r = [myString rangeOfString:@"_"];
NSString *res = [myString substringToIndex:r.location];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
NSString *Xs = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try componentsSeparatedByString: under the heading Dividing Strings.

[NSString Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)